# $ \iint_D \frac{x^3}{x^2 + y^2} dA; D := {(x − 1)^2 + y^2 ≤ 1} ∩ {y ≥ 0}$

Tags: calculus, integration, quadratics, fractions

I encountered the following question online:

> Evaluate
> $$
> \iint_D
> \frac{x^3}{x^2 + y^2}
> dA$$
> where D is the region
> $$D := {(x − 1)^2 + y^2 ≤ 1} ∩ {y ≥ 0}$$

Could you begin by stating your approach and how to deal with similar problems in the future. This seems so fundamental but I haven't dealt with this problem type yet.

Also, note an application this problem type has and an intuition as to how one would come to construct this problem. Please elucidate sufficiently for those new to this domain.

Comment: Hint: The polar curve $r=d \cos(\theta)$ represents a circle of diameter $d$ centered around the point $(d/2,0)$.

Comment: The most obvious approach is to work with shifted polar coordinates $x=1+r\cos\theta,y=r\sin\theta$ in which case $D$ is parametrized by $(r,\theta)\in[0,1]\times [0,\pi]$. The resulting double integral is not especially nice (though is tractable if one converts the integral over $\theta$ into a contour integration). Also, it may be worth noting that the restriction to $y\geq 0$ is not especially interesting: the integrand is even w/r/t $y\to -y$, so including that constraint only changes the answer by a factor of $2$.

Comment: @Semiclassical regular polar coordinates works far better, especially if you integrate w.r.t. the angular variable first (hence the usefulness of the restriction as well).